# why running jacoco 0.8.8 with junit 5 does not generate the jacoco files

Tags: maven-3, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

we have jacoco v0.8.8 and junit5 (jupiter) on maven 3.5.4
when we are running the mvn build with tests on our java files we see the tests are running but we dont see on the project target area that the jacoco reports were generated.
for junit4 we see that the files are generated.

we have configured pom.xml file with these plugins:

```
<plugin>
                             <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                              <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                              <version>0.8.8</version>
                              <configuration>
                                          <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}/destFile>
                                           <excludes>**/test/*</excludes>
                              </configuration>
                               <executions>
                                           <execution>
                                                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                                                         <goals>
                                                                   <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                                         </goals>
                                                        <configuration>
                                                                        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</destFile>
                                                        </configuration>
                                            </execution>
                                    <execution>
                                         <id>post-unit-test</id>
                                                           <phase>test</phase>
                                                            <goals>
                                                             <goal>report</goal>
                                                           </goals>
                                                          <configuration>
                                                            <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</dataFile>
                                                           </configuration>
                                             </execution>
                                  </executions>
               </plugin>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                             <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                              <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                              <configuration>
                                <statelessTestsetReporter
implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5Xml30StatelessReporter">
                                           <usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>
                                           <usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>
                                             </statelessTestsetReporter>
                                             <argLine>-Xmx1048m</argLine>
                                             <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                                 </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

when we run the mvn command we dont see the jacoco files.
mvn clean verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dsonar.projectKey=project_key -Dsonar.projectName=project_name -DprojectVersion=1111.01 -Dsonar.sources=src/main/java -Dsonar.exclusions=

when we run it with junit4 it does work and generate jacoco files.
what are we missing?

Comment: First why not using most recent versions of plugins jacoco-maven-plugin and maven-surefire-plugin also the question is do you have two deps defined like JUnit 5 and JUnit 4 ? Please show your full pom file..also you should upgrade your Maven version ...